# Authentication.AuthenticateAsync returns null

Tags: c#, owin, access-token, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I want to get my Azure B2C AD access token from the httpContext or similar, but I am using .NET framework 4.7.2. If I was using .Net core, I would use `HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync()` .

**Background**

I am using OpenIdConnect 4.1.0.

My OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions looks like this:

```
private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromSiteConfig(B2CConfig config)
{
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions();
    options.MetadataAddress = string.Format(_aadInstance, _tenant, config.Policy);
    options.AuthenticationType = [B2CAD-POLICY-name];
    options.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
    options.RedirectUri = config.AzureReplyUri;
    options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = config.LogoutRedirectUri;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "emails"
    };

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.RedeemCode = true;

    var identityProvider = GetIdentityProvider();

    options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,

        RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(notification.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = config.UiLocale ?? string.Empty);
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
        {
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", "azureadb2c"));

            // transform all claims
            ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
            notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };

    options.ClientId = config.ClientId;
    options.Scope = "openid [api-scope-here]";
    options.ResponseType = "id_token token";

    return options;
}
```

There is multiple policies with the same name (i.e. multiple AuthenticationTypes with same name).

So far, I have found several suggestions, where the most promising one suggested:

```
var result = await owinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync([B2CAD-POLICY-name]));
string token = result.Properties.Dictionary["access_token"];
```

However, the result is always NULL, eventhough I have verified that the b2cad policy is actually present in the OwinContext.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for that? I would appreciate, if you can share it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution - sorry

Comment: I have the same problem and have not yet found the solution  :W